# How To change CDR logs "Master.csv" , asterisk logs, to Data Wise

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, cdr

Greeting Day to all of you,Hope you are doing well.

I have a small questions :
I wanted to change my `Master.csv` `file` format into `date-wise csv file` because it will manage easily and will be readable too.
Also tell me the process how to change `asterisk logs file format` into `date-wise`.
`Asterisk logs path details:`

```
/var/log/asterisk/ files are messages, queue_log, full and also zip too
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite asterisk log file format by any external script.

Such script can be writed in perl for example and very simple. Acordinly to SO rules you have show your effort in triing do such script, full solutions is offtopic here.

You can change Master.csv using cdr-custom module

http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/cdr_custom_conf.html

```
[mappings]
Master.csv => "${CDR(clid)}","${CDR(src)}","${CDR(dst)}","${CDR(dcontext)}","${CDR(channel)}","${CDR(dstchannel)}","${CDR(lastapp)}","${CDR(lastdata)}","${CDR(start)}","${CDR(answer)}","${CDR(end)}","${CDR(duration)}","${CDR(billsec)}","${CDR(disposition)}","${CDR(amaflags)}","${CDR(accountcode)}","${CDR(uniqueid)}","${CDR(userfield)}"


Let's have a closer look at the variables we can define here:

${CDR(clid)} = callerid for the call (with the name)
${CDR(src)} = callerid number for the call
${CDR(dst)} = destination extension
${CDR(dcontext)} = Destination context
${CDR(channel)} = Src channel
${CDR(dstchannel)} = Destination channel if appropriate
${CDR(lastapp)} = this is the last application in the dialplan used, on an outgoing call this will be DIAL.
${CDR(lastdata)} = these are the parameters given to the last application used in the dialplan
${CDR(start)} = time of the start of the call
${CDR(answer)} = time when the call was answered
${CDR(end)} = time when the call got hung up
${CDR(duration)} = duration of the call
${CDR(billsec)} = duration of the actual call (without the ringing)
${CDR(disposition)} = status of the call (ANSWERED, BUSY, NO ANSWER)
${CDR(amaflags)} = flag for the type of CDR (can be set in a.o. sip.conf)
default: Sets the system default.
omit: Do not record calls.
billing: Mark the entry for billing
documentation: Mark the entry for documentation.

${CDR(accountcode)} = the accountcode as set for this channel with for example SetAccountcode in the dialplan (Extensions.conf) or in the channel configuration file (e.g. per user in sip.conf, iax.conf and per channel in zaptel.conf)
${CDR(uniqueid)} = a unique id for this call
{CDR(userfield)} = a userfield set by the dialplan command SetCDRUserfield

As you can see, it is possible to define different "layouts" for different files.
The default file is Master.csv, but if you specify a different accountcode (with SetAccount or in sip.conf or iax.conf or zaptel.conf) the filename will change.
```

Comment: But I need csv file to Date wise for example it's shows like Master.csv and every day file is appended to the existing one .I want file format like that Master_dd_mm_yyyy.csv

Comment: logrotate will help you change file name every day.